# Why the first Chern class of a line bundle can be non-zero

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, curvature, characteristic-classes, line-bundles

According to Chern-Weil theory Chern forms $c_i$ of the vector bundle $\xi : E \to M$ are determined by the polynomial
$$
\det\left(I  + \frac{\mathrm{i}t}{2\pi}F  \right) = 1 + \sum^n_{i=1} c_i(\xi) t^i,
$$
where $F$ is a curvature form determined by the connection form $\omega$ as
$$
F = \mathrm{d}\omega + [\omega \wedge \omega].
$$
Now Chern class is the homological class $[c_i(\xi)]$.

It is evident that for the line bundle $\xi$ and for any $i > 1$ it holds that $c_i(\xi)$ what I can't understand is that why $[c_1(\xi)] \neq 0$ for nontrivial line bundles.

In case of line bundle expression above simplifies to

$$
\det\left(I  + \frac{it}{2\pi}F  \right) = 1 + \frac{it}{2\pi} F
$$
But on the line bundle $\omega$ is just a differential form, so 
$
 F = \mathrm{d}\omega 
$ as $\omega \wedge \omega = 0 $.  Hence, $c_1(\xi) = \frac{i}{2\pi} d \omega$ is an exact form, and so $[c_1(\xi)] = 0$. But this contradicts many results concerning line bundles!

> It seems that I don't understand something either about definition of Chern class or about the cutvature form. Please help me find my mistakes.

Comment: Why do you say that $\omega$ is just a differential form?

Comment: if $n = \mathrm{rank}\; \xi$, then locally $\omega$ can be represented a $n \times n$ matrix if differential forms. However, in case $n=1$ the resulting matrix is $1 \times 1$.

Comment: In contrast to the globally defined curvature $2$-form $F$, the connection $1$-form $\omega$ is only defined locally. Therefore the local equation $F=d\omega$ only shows that $F$ is closed, not exact.

Comment: @NikPronko are you okay with this explanation?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you wrote down in your argument for vanishing first Chern-class, would work if the bundle was trivial in the first place. This is exactly what Peter wrote.

Remember (assuming standard literature) that said expression is a result on local trivialisations, for $\omega$ the local connection form.

So your argument works locally, but that is of course not the point.

The real question is now: "why is vanishing first Chern-class equivalent to being trivial for line bundles?"